# How to ask an employer to relieve me earlier than my notice period?

Tags: conversations, work-environment

Background:
I have been working with an employer for the past 10 months. While interviewing me they asked questions related to my previous job profile, but when I joined here I found that the job profile is completely different.

Along with different job profile there are lots of politics in the office. It's a relatively small office with 14 people, seven of whom are relatives of my boss. My team lead doesn't know anything about the job. They can't even evaluate the task properly let alone know about details. I came to know about these within a month of joining. I started to look for something else and I found one. Now I have resigned from here.

In past 4 months they have not assigned me any worthy tasks and have now assigned me something which they want me to finish asap. The task is totally new to me and is in a different domain. I have been asking for help over mails but they don't reply.

The task is pretty complex. I have been searching online for days and I couldn't find a workable solution. My notice period is 3 months. I have served for 20 days. Now, I want them to relieve me since it's very difficult for me to work effectively in this situation. Since I have been working continuously for last 3 years I also want to have some break for myself.

So, How I can ask my employer to relieve me early, since I am not the right person for that job and it's a waste of both of our time and resources for me to serve my entire notice period?

Comment: Welcome to Interpersonal.SE! I can't help wondering whether this might be better suited to Workplace.SE.

Comment: @F1Krazy I agree the question crosses over, but Workplace.SE may take a more 'legal' approach to the question of notice - the OP has made their mind up that they want to leave early and is asking how to express this. I think it is perfectly suited here.

Comment: Where does this take place?  Notice period in the US is very different than from India, for example.

Comment: This seems like less of an IPS issue than it is a [workplace.se] issue but they really need a location in order to be welcoming of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Employment laws covering notice periods will vary depending on where you live. There may be statutory requirements under law, and most likely your contract of employment will include a specified period of leave. But obviously your employer chooses to enforce this for their own benefit. You can mutually agree to adjust it.

In my experience in the UK, standard notice is one month. Three months is normally only in contracts for positions of high responsibility or where the role will be more difficult to fill with a candidate of the same experience. Perhaps this applies to you, but you say that you have been given a task for which you have little experience! If your employer is just trying to fill the 3 months by giving you an arbitrary task then perhaps this is your "bargaining chip".

You may be successful in negotiating a shorter period of notice if you can convince your employer that:

1. You are not the best person for the task he has given you,
2. There is no benefit to keeping you on that long,
3. That your remaining time could be used better.

Before you approach him, check the facts. Be certain what your contract says about your notice period. It may also be useful to know what your local employment laws say about statutory notice periods, especially as you have worked for the company for less than a year.

Ask to meet with him privately and perhaps say:

> Please can I talk to you about my remaining notice? I know that we
>   have agreed 3 months notice, but if possible I would like to leave
>   earlier.

Remember your boss may not have even considered that you would want to leave earlier. Notice periods are there to protect both employer and employee, and it may be he has just assumed you will work that notice and given you this task to fill the time?

If he needs more convincing, perhaps go on to say:

> The task I am currently undertaking is not really in my area of
>   expertise. I may be able to complete it satisfactorily, but there may
>   be no time for anything else. I think that it would be more beneficial to
>   you if I used the time to hand over my work to my successor (either
>   training if you are already working with them, or writing handover
>   documents). Can we agree a shorter notice period and I will work on my
>   handover to that deadline?

Even if you don't succeed in convincing him immediately, this may plant the thought in his mind that if you don't really want to be there working 3 months notice you may not be highly motivated, and really he is wasting his money paying you to work with reduced motivation and productivity.

If there really is no way to convince him, you have a few choices open to you (which aren't exactly interpersonal solutions but this is supplemental to my answer):

1. Accept it and work to the best of your ability. Remember you may need a reference from him someday so it might be a good idea to keep him happy.
2. Accept it, but just work at whatever pace you feel like. He can't keep you beyond your agreed notice period, so just take it easy. This might endanger your good reference, and at worst if you breach your working conditions seriously he could terminate your employment which gets you out of working there but won't look good on your employment history.
3. If you are desperate to get out you *could* challenge it from a legal point of view *if* your contract and employments laws allow you reason to, but DO get separate advice on that.

Comment: Why would you post an answer based on UK law when there's no indication that the OP is in the UK? That part of your answer isn't even IPS-relevant. Please remember, this is IPS, not TWP and make sure your answer focuses on the IPS **not** the Workplace content.